# My windows services read different registry path from a application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

I wrote a ConsoleApplication with C#, all its work was just call some function of dll(Dynamic Link Libarary), and Init() was one of these funcations, it will read registry path as HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CompanyName\ConfigFolder, well, this ConsoleApplication run well at the moment.
However, I was told to write a same function program but in a form of windows services. OK, C#.NET writes Windows Services project conveniently. I just copied my ConsoleApplication's code and modified a litte. But the problem is that I found it would not read the former register path (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CompanyName\ConfigFolder),so  that Init() funcation doesn't work now. I want to know what is the correct registry path that a Windows Services will read.
PS: The first time my ConsoleApplication run, the registry path HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CompanyName\ConfigFolder did not exist, so this Init() funcation would search a configuration file named "config.ini"  under the current path, after that, it would write that configuration into registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CompanyName\ConfigFolder). Howerver, when I turned my application into a Windows Services, not matter I put the config.ini into project current path or C:\Windows\System32, it all didn't work. My Operation System is Windows 7.

Comment: Under which user does your windows service run? That should be a clue.

Comment: I hope you are not one of the people who never show code in posts, but when they do all exceptions are eaten/ignored with `catch(Exception){}`. Please post error messages that happen and account you run service under.

Answer (score 2):

What's the error it gives? Or does it not give an error? if its about read/write access right to the registry, make sure you're running the service under **LOCALSYSTEM** or **Administrator**

Comment: Thanks, I have found the answer: set the service under User Account. So that it runs like a application, just like your said.